# How to deal with error of incorrect syntax near keyword user

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am building a school management system as a Windows application in C#. I used a local database and Visual Studio 2017; I try to insert data into a table:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\zar_m\source\repos\SIS2\SIS2\SISDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

con.Open();

string sql_Text = "INSERT INTO user Values(@user_id,@name,@fathername,@username,@password,@email,@gender,@dob,@date_of_join,@contact,@address)";
//(user_id, name, fathername, username, password, email, gender, dob, date_of_join, contact, address)

using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO user VALUSE(@user_id, @name, @fathername, @username, @password, @email, @gender, @dob, @date_of_join, @contact, @address)", con))
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", user_idTextBox.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameTextBox.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fathername", fathernameTextBox.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameTextBox.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordTextBox.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailTextBox.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender",genderTextBox.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dobTextBox.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_of_join", date_of_joinTextBox.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", contactTextBox.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", addressTextBox.Text);

    int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    if (i != 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(i + "Data Saved");
    }
}
```

The code seems ok, but I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near keyword user

Please help me - thank you

Comment: User is a keyword as it states in the error, keywords used as field/table names must be wrapped in [ ] for Microsoft databases so change `user` to `[user]`. I would also suggest you not get in the habit of not explicitly listing your field names for the values.

Comment: Values is spellt wrong.... "VALUSE"

Comment: thank you so much it worked by adding [] and correct values spelling.

Comment: Curious to know why you repeated the sql string when you created the SqlCommand.. why didn't you just say `new SqlCommand(sql_Text, con)`?

Comment: ps when CharlesMay says *"I would also suggest you not get in the habit of not explicitly listing your field names for the values"* I believe he is recommending "always list the columns you want to insert into, like this: `INSERT INTO table(columnName1, colimnName2) VALUES (value1, value2)`"

Comment: did it as such now.  it is done just for identifying error.

Comment: If you don't list the columns and just rely on the shortcut of "don't need to list columns if the values list has the same number of values as the number of non-autoincrement columns in the table", then your query will stop working if a column is added to the table. Adding columns is often done, and usually of minimal nuisance to existing queries. Providing a column list will ensure your query carries on working (so long as any new columns are specified as nullable/have a default value)

Comment: @parii, avoid using reserved [T-SQL keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) like `USER` as object/column names. This will avoid the need to enclose identifiers in double-quotes or square brackets.

Comment: Also, avoid [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Answer (score 3):

If a keyword is used as an identifier, like a table or column name, it must be quoted. I.e. put square brackets around `user` in your query.

```
INSERT INTO [user] VALUES (@user_id, @name, @fathername, @username, @password, @email, @gender, @dob, @date_of_join, @contact, @address)
```

And BTW, it's `VALUES`, you wrote `VALUSE`. And it is a good idea to explicitly list the targeted columns in an `INSERT` statement, like

```
INSERT INTO [user] (id, name, ...) VALUES ...
```

so that the statement still works even when the number or order of columns in the table changes for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In the line below you have misspelled **VALUES** instead you typed of **VALUSE**

```
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO user VALUSE(@user_id, @name, @fathername, @username, @password, @email, @gender, @dob, @date_of_join, @contact, @address)", con))
```